# Как получить строку из POST-запроса на php?

Tags: php, json, post

Как следует из документации платёжной системы, страница получает уведомление через $_POST, которое содержит json-строку вида:

{"id":"fb4def00b68d9bd805c160db1993de7d1ed7579f","status":"accepted_successed","message":"","amount":"542.0", "old_amount": "1000.0"}

У меня не выходит получить эту строку! Логирую содержимое POST-запросов с получением содержимого функциями var_dump($_POST) и print_r($_POST); в итоге  пусто. Содержимое $_POST тоже пустое.

Как получить строку из $_POST в PHP?

Логировал следующим образом:

```
if (!empty($_POST)) {
    $fw = fopen(file.txt, "a");
    fwrite($fw, "POST " . var_export($_POST, true));
    fclose($fw);
}
```

Comment: А как ты запрос отсылаешь?

Comment: Их отсылает платёжная система, не я.

Comment: Ну она же в ответ на что-то отсылает? Ты же делаешь куда-то запрос, чтобы тебе отдали ответ? Или ты просто ждёшь, что какая-то платёжка внезапно тебе будет данные слать?

Comment: Когда кто-то оплачивает на их странице, они оповещают от этом POST-запросом. Конечно, перед этим создаётся счет, я им отправляю тоже запрос для этого, но входящее уведомление об оплате не имеет к этому никакого отношения. Оно просто приходит в какой-то момент, я его не инициирую каким-то своим действием.

Comment: Окей. То есть они как минимум должны отослать данные на какой-то конкретный URL, который ты им укажешь, правильно?  А как ты смотришь данные из пост запроса? Просто в браузере ждёшь что что-то появится? или в отладчике ожидаешь подхватывания брейкпойнта?

Comment: на странице, на которую приходит запрос, я написал скрипт, который логирует содержимое POST-запросов в текстовый файл. Обновил текст вопроса, добавил код. Таким образом, я пытаюсь их отлавливать. Так же использовал функции print_r() и var_dump(). Но у меня не получается, возможно, я ошибаюсь, поэтому я и спросил, как правильно это сделать.

Comment: `var_dump(json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'), true));`

Answer (score 0):

Я, например, делаю так:

```
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {
if (isset($_POST)) {
    echo "OK";
    $postData = $_POST;
    $post_text = print_r($postData, true);
    file_put_contents('./file.txt', "Content: $post_text \n", FILE_APPEND); die;
```

"file.txt" не забудь о правах
[Взято отсюда](https://ae-nekrasov.ru/development/code-snippets/sohranit-massiv-v-fajl-php/)